# How to properly do sorting under aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am still new to elasticSearch, and i have a doubt here. Would like to get assits. I have some error on properly do sorting under aggregation. Please advice me. Thank YOu

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
    {
      "range": {
        "ts": {
          "gt": "2016-08-22T00:00:00.000Z",
          "lt": "2016-08-23T13:41:09.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
  },
  "aggs": {
"group_by_ip": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "id_orig_h"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sum_volume": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "resp_bytes",
        "sort": [
          {
            "resp_bytes": {
              "order": "asc"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the `order` setting in your `terms` aggregation referencing the `sum_volume` sub-aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "ts": {
              "gt": "2016-08-22T00:00:00.000Z",
              "lt": "2016-08-23T13:41:09.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_ip": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id_orig_h",
        "order": {
          "sum_volume": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_volume": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "resp_bytes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @val, i just got it few minutes ago too. I am so happy as i start to catch some theory behind right now after guided by you this morning.
once again thank you. 
Btw, can you teach me how to do sum between two field ? field1 + field2 ?